# How to decouple functionality and logging in a ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I like to log a lot. In my Rails app I have a lot of methods like:

```
def my_method(argument1:, argument2:)
  logger.info "Starting my_method with arguments: #{argument1} and #{argument2}"
  result = argument1 + argument2
  logger.info "Finished my_method with result: #{result}"
end
```

**How to decouple the functionality and the logging of the methods?**.

Ideally the result would look something like this (borrowing the callback concept from Rails just as an example):

```
before_method: :my_method_log_start, only: :my_method
after_method: :my_method_log_end, only: :my_method

def my_method(argument1:, argument2:)
  result = argument1 + argument2
end

private

def my_method_log_start
  logger.info "Starting my_method with arguments: #{argument1} and #{argument2}"
end

def my_method_log_end
  logger.info "Finished my_method with result: #{result}"
end
```

I know this is less efficient in terms of lines of code, it is more readable (in my opinion).

I have read about Aspect Orient Programming and some of their gems like Aquarius, but looks like an overkill to add a new paradigm just for logging.

Comment: There is [a performance overhead](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#impact-of-logs-on-performance) to adding a bunch of log statements - I would suggest you learn how to use a debugger or write tests instead of relying on logs as a crutch for poor technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [Avdi Grimm](https://www.rubytapas.com/2017/04/11/skinny-controller-domain-model-events/) has a good explanation of the technique you could use. The idea is to extract logging (or anything else) to the listener class and publish events to that listener, basic example would be

```
class Task
  # ...
  def add_listener(listener)
    (@listeners ||= []) << listener
  end
  # ...

  def notify_listeners(event_name, *args)
    @listeners && @listeners.each do |listener|
      if listener.respond_to?(event_name)
        listener.public_send(event_name, self, *args)
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

and do sth like

```
task = Task.new
task.add_lestener(YourLoggerClass.new)
task.notify_listeners(:start_logging)
task.notify_listeners(:end_logging)
```

Comment: The is basically the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

If this is only for local debugging, it is the good use case for `TracePoint` class. Here is the code:

```
tp1 = TracePoint.new do |tp|
  if tp.event == :call
    method = tp.defined_class.method(tp.method_id)
    arguments = method.parameters.map do |param|
      "#{param[1]}: #{tp.binding.local_variable_get(param[1])}"
    end.join(", ")
    puts "Starting #{tp.method_id} with arguments #{arguments}"
  elsif tp.event.to_s == "return"
    puts "Finished #{tp.method_id} with result: #{tp.return_value}"
  end
end

tp1.enable

def my_method1(a, b)
  a + b
end

puts my_method1(2, 3)
```

I recommend reading the documentation for this class, it has really nice features. Of course you need to polish this code a little bit to handle some edge cases. You can add some filter to only invoke tracing block for methods that you care about. Or you can enable/disable this based on some parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can call method by it's name, or turn it to proc and pass to another method. So you can write something like that:

```
def foo(a, b)
  a + b
end

def call_with_logging(method_name, *args)
  args_as_string = args.map(&:to_s).join(' ')
  puts "Starting my_method with arguments #{args_as_string}"
  result = Object.send(method_name, *args)
  puts "Finished my_method with result: #{result}"
end

call_with_logging :foo, 1, 2
```